# How to parse this repsonse in restkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am confused completely to parse this kind of response in restkit. I am using this [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#handling-dynamic-nesting-attributes) but i am not able to understand how to parse this response.Any help would be appreciated.

```
“groups”: {
      "group1": [
        {        
         "email": "blake@restkit.org",        
         "favorite_animal": "Monkey"    
        },
        {        
         "email": "slake@restkit.org",        
         "favorite_animal": "Donkey"    
        }
      ],    
      "group2": [
        {
         "email": "sarah@restkit.org",   
         "favorite_animal": "Cat"
        },
        {
         "email": "varah@restkit.org",   
         "favorite_animal": "Cow"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am Using Below mapping.

```
@interface GroupResponse : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Groups;

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping;

@end

@implementation GroupResponse

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
    [objectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@“groups” toKeyPath:@“Groups” withMapping:[GroupData mapping]]];

    return objectMapping;
}
@end



@interface GroupData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *groupName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *arrPersons;

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping;

@end

@implementation GroupData

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];

    objectMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"groupName"];

    [objectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@“(groupName)” toKeyPath:@"arrPersons" withMapping:[Person mapping]]];

    return objectMapping;
}

@end


@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *favAnimal;

+ (RKObjectMapping *) mapping;
@end

@implementation Person

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];

    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"email" : @"email",
                                                        @"favorite_animal" : @"favAnimal"}];

    return objectMapping;
}

@end
```

Everytime **arrPersons** is nil. How to do proper mapping in this case.

Comment: What code have you tried?  Are you using `NSJSONSerialization` ?  It looks quite straightforward - a dictionary where each key contains an array of dictionaries

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, It can be done using NSJSONSerialization. but I am using RestKit for Object mapping.

Comment: Ok so can you show what you have tried with that framework?

Comment: Confused about what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attribute:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *arrPersons;
```

should actually be a mutable array, not a string type:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrPersons;
```

because the nested JSON array can't be converted into a string and your mapping indicates that it should be processed into an array of `Person` objects.

Comment: Oh! that was a silly mistake by me. Thanks for the help Wain. It is working fine now